# PyQt5: QWebEngineView can't render local html file in Windows 7

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I am building an PyQt5 app with QWebEngineView. The html file is read by BeautifulSoup, which prettifies it then show it using QtWebEngineView. My code is like the following:

```
class HTMLRenderer(QWebEngineView):

     def __init__(self):
          super(HTMLRenderer, self).__init__(parent)
          self.soup = BeautifulSoup(open('../template/email.html', 'r').read(), 'html.parser')
          self.render()

     def render(self):
          self.setHtml(self.soup.prettify())
          self.show()
```

But the QtWebEngineView is blank. It fails to show anything.

I'm developing on Windows 7. The whole code works on Mac OS. But now I want to have it worked on Windows 7.

It seems that QWebEngineView has problems on Windows.

Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to "skip" this bug by pasting the entire url path. Seems that relative paths dont get rendered.